# Understanding of innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is part of the definition for "innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit". If the value of innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is 0, the log buffer is written out to the log file once per second and the flush to disk operation is performed on the log file, but nothing is done at a transaction commit.

I am a little confused. Are "the log buffer is written out to the log file" and "the flush to disk operation is performed on the log file" the same thing? "the flush to disk operation is performed on the log file" means flush the log buffer to the log file on disk, correct?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the key of your confusion is OS buffer.

[image]

### Reference

https://www.cnblogs.com/f-ck-need-u/p/9010872.html